# Change the link color for responsive ad unit

Tags: css, adsense

In the "older" adsense ad units I was able to change the link color of the ad so it matches the page style using `google_color_link` and `google_color_url` parameters.

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "pub-XXXXXX";
/* 120x600, created 10/10/10 */
google_ad_slot = "XXXXXX";
google_ad_width = 120;
google_ad_height = 600;
google_color_link="11aa11";
google_color_url="11aa11";
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

How can I do the same with new responsive ad unit?

```
<script async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
<!-- responsive test -->
<ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:block"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXXXX"
     data-ad-slot="XXXXX"
     data-ad-format="auto">
</ins>
<script>
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

I suspect it might be a part of `style` attribute, but can't find a reference or example.

Comment: Pull up the page in question, do an f12 and inspect the ad and find out the style name for the google links. You can then add a style with the same name to your page and decorate it with !important which will override their style, i.e. google_color_url { color: #123212 !important;}

Comment: @haahon319 Even if it works it will likely be violation of adsense T&C. Non-responsive ad unit had documented(?) api to tweak the color. I'm looking for the similar one for responsive ads.